# Whose phone number is the one referred at "We will call you at <phone number>"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I just got an interview and the email said "We will call you at [a phone number that doesn't belong to me]". Does the phone number here refer to to their phone number, or they just got my phone number wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically (AmE), we use ***at*** to indicate the number receiving the call, and we use ***from*** to indicate the number making the call:

> 1. 1. We will call you ***at*** [**your** number].
>    2. Have a comment? Please call us ***at*** [**company** number].
> 2. 1. We will call you ***from*** [**interviewer's** number].
>    2. We need to talk. Please call us ***from*** [**your** number].

In your example, it sounds like the phone number should be **your** number. It seems like a mistake and you should contact them to correct it.

Comment: It's common, and not AmE! Nevertheless, *We'll call you on....* also works!

Comment: It's just a standard disclaimer. Preposition usage is quite finicky and can vary by region. _Call you on [number]_ seems like it's acceptable in some places, but it sounds strange to me. That's why could be helpful to include a region. Also, if I tried to accept it, it would be ambiguous to me. That's just me though.

Comment: *Strange!* At least I practice *calling **on** <number>* but *calling **at** <place i.e. residence>.*

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely that they got the wrong number.

They're not going to call themselves and the wording of the sentence doesn't indicate that they're asking you to call them.

That only leaves them calling the number they gave in order to reach you. (If it's not yours, you should reply to them with the correct number.)